# Программа работает не как нужно JAVA-core

Tags: java

Задание: Удаление лишних символов с номера телефона
С проверкой в длину цифр

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortByNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Ведите номер телефона");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String number = scan.nextLine();
    
    String seven = "7";
    String last = "";
            
    if(number != null) {
        String clearNumber = number.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
        System.out.println(clearNumber);
        if(clearNumber.length()== 10) {
            String numberToSQL = seven + clearNumber;
            last = numberToSQL;
        }
        if(clearNumber.length()== 11){
            char fisrtChar = clearNumber.charAt(0);
            if(fisrtChar == 7) {
                String numberToSQL = clearNumber;
                last = numberToSQL;
            }
            if(fisrtChar == 8) {
                String s = null;
                s = clearNumber.substring(1);
                String numberToSQL = seven + s;
                last = numberToSQL;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Номер не указан или не верный формат");
    }
    
    System.out.println("Ваш номер - " + last);
```

Comment: Я допустил ошибку, сравнив примитив char с int
Решение: 
объявить переменные и сравнить с ними

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение
сравнил **char** и **char**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortByNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("ВВедите номер телефона");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String number = scan.nextLine();
    
    String seven = "7";
    char seven1 = '7' ;
    char eight = '8';
    String last = "";
            
    if(number != null) {
        String clearNumber = number.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
        System.out.println(clearNumber);
        if(clearNumber.length()== 10) {
            String numberToSQL = seven + clearNumber;
            last = numberToSQL;
        }
        if(clearNumber.length()== 11){
            char fisrtChar = clearNumber.charAt(0);
            if(fisrtChar == seven1) {
                String numberToSQL = clearNumber;
                last = numberToSQL;
            }
            if(fisrtChar == eight) {
                String s = null;
                s = clearNumber.substring(1);
                String numberToSQL = seven + s;
                last = numberToSQL;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Номер не указан или не верный формат");
    }
    
    System.out.println("Ваш номер - " + last);
    
}

}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]